# How can I do a DICOM query and retrieve from a Ginkgo PACS (or any other) using dcm4che

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

I'm writing a "simple" HL7 listener and then using the `dcm4che` binary utility `movescu` to make a query and retrieve operation from a remote PACS

I need to retrieve a Study and I have (00080050) AccessionNumber from the HL7 data, then I do the following:

```
./movescu -b LOCALAET@{local_ip}:044 -c REMOTEAET@{remote_ip}:104 --dest LOCALAET@{local_ip}:104 -m 00080050={known_accession_number}
```

with a remote PACS I am getting this:

```
(0000,0002) UI [1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2] AffectedSOPClassUID
(0000,0100) US [32801] CommandField
(0000,0120) US [1] MessageIDBeingRespondedTo
(0000,0800) US [257] CommandDataSetType
(0000,0900) US [49152] Status
(0000,0902) LO [Error querying db (ImageRetrieve)] ErrorComment
(0000,1020) US [0] NumberOfRemainingSuboperations
(0000,1021) US [0] NumberOfCompletedSuboperations
(0000,1022) US [0] NumberOfFailedSuboperations
(0000,1023) US [0] NumberOfWarningSuboperations
```

And with a local Ginkgo I am getting:

```
17:12:58,906 DEBUG - LOCALAET->REMOTEAET(1): enter state: Sta6 - Association established and ready for data transfer
17:12:58,946 INFO  - LOCALAET->REMOTEAET(1) >> A-ABORT[source: 0 - service-user, reason: 0]
17:12:58,946 INFO  - LOCALAET->REMOTEAET(1): close Socket[addr=/XXX.XXX.X.XX,port=8080,localport=36105]
17:12:58,947 DEBUG - LOCALAET->REMOTEAET(1): enter state: Sta1 - Idle
movescu: Sta1 - Idle
org.dcm4che3.net.AssociationStateException: Sta1 - Idle
    at org.dcm4che3.net.State.writeAReleaseRQ(State.java:223)
    at org.dcm4che3.net.Association.release(Association.java:326)
    at org.dcm4che3.tool.movescu.MoveSCU.close(MoveSCU.java:331)
    at org.dcm4che3.tool.movescu.MoveSCU.main(MoveSCU.java:268)
```

(using different port on Ginkgo)

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the Ginkgo PACS, but quite likely your retrieval fails because your request is malformed.

**See PS3.4, C.4.2.1.4.1 Request Identifier Structure**

Your request must include the attribute Query Retrieve Level (0008,0052) which I assume will be "STUDY" in your case since the Accession Number is a study-level attribute.

Furthermore it must contain

> "Unique Key Attributes, which may include Patient ID (0010,0020),
> Study Instance UIDs (0020,000D), Series Instance UIDs (0020,000E), and
> the SOP Instance UIDs (0008,0018)"

That is, you have to specify the scope of your retrieve request by providing unique identifiers for the patient/study/series/image(s) you want to move - *and nothing else!*

So Accession Number may be used to query (C-FIND) for the corresponding Study Instance UID that you need for the C-MOVE. But it is not allowed in the C-MOVE-Request.

**Caution:** Whether or not you must include or omit the Patient-ID (0010,0020) in your C-MOVE request depends on the information model that you have negotiated during association establishment and that you select by choosing the presentation context for your message. You must include it in Patient Root, you must not include it in Study Root.

Comment: This is partially right, I solved this using C-FIND first to get the Study UID and then used C-GET instead of C-MOVE... and yes, I'm sending STUDY level in my command

Comment: Also you are right, in order to make C-GET work I had to send the (0020, 000D) tag AND the (0008, 0050) in the request to make it valid, not just the (0020, 000D)